# How to move marker in google maps 5px down?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, primefaces-gmap

I have simple question maby somebody know if it is possibility to move all markers in google maps left or right or whatever?
If somebody have idea how i have simple code:

```
(function() {PrimeFaces.cw('GMap','widget_j_idt21',{
        id:'j_idt21',
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.735512733,19.49804157),
        zoom:14,
        fitBounds:false
    });
});
```

To better unterstand i past image i want to line on map start in the middle of circle

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a custom icon and use `iconAnchor` to specify an offset...

```
var Icon = new GIcon();
    Icon.image = "icon.png";
    Icon.iconSize = new GSize(24, 24);
    Icon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(0, 5);
    Icon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(5, 2);
```

Comment: The posted code is for the Google Maps API v2, not v3 as this question is tagged.  But the answer is correct in principle.  Both APIs support custom icons for this purpose.

Comment: But i still dont know how to intercept icons that are generated?